# GCP IP address range

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to resolve my issue with the Terraform code to create Load Balancer based on the official documentation for the Application Load Balancer with MIG/url map/forwarding and backend services: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-http-lb-tf-module-examples#with_mig_backend_and_custom_headers

I do not know what he is talking to me about because my IP address is in the range which is 10.0.0.0/24.

This is my configuration:

```
# VPC network
resource "google_compute_network" "great-ilb_network" {
  name                    = "great-l7-ilb-network"
  auto_create_subnetworks = false
  project                 = var.project_id
}

# proxy-only subnet
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "great-proxy_subnet" {
  name          = "great-l7-ilb-proxy-subnet"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.0.0.0/24"
  network       = google_compute_network.great-ilb_network.self_link
}

# backend subnet
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "great-ilb_subnet" {
  name          = "great-l7-ilb-subnet"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.0.1.0/24"
  region        = var.region
  network       = google_compute_network.great-ilb_network.self_link
}

# MIG
resource "google_compute_instance_group_manager" "great-instance_group_manager" {
  name               = "my-great-instance-group-manager"
  base_instance_name = "my-instance"
  target_size        = 4

  version {
    instance_template = google_compute_instance_template.great-instance_template.self_link
  }
}

# instance template
resource "google_compute_instance_template" "great-instance_template" {
  name         = "my-great-instance-template"
  machine_type = var.vm_config.vm_type

  disk {
    source_image = "debian-cloud/debian-10"
    auto_delete  = true
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"
    access_config {}
  }

  metadata_startup_script = var.vm_config.vm_startup_script
}

# Backend Service
resource "google_compute_backend_service" "fancy-fe-frontend" {
  name                = "fancy-fe-frontend"
  project             = var.project_id
  port_name           = "frontend"
  health_checks       = [google_compute_health_check.http-health-check.self_link]
  backend {
    group           = google_compute_instance_group_manager.great-instance_group_manager.instance_group
  }
  protocol            = "HTTP"
  timeout_sec         = 10
  load_balancing_scheme = "EXTERNAL"
}

# HTTP Health Check
resource "google_compute_health_check" "http-health-check" {
  name                  = "great-fancy-fe-frontend-hc"
  project               = var.project_id

  timeout_sec        = 1
  check_interval_sec = 1

  http_health_check {
    port = 80
  }
}

# forwarding rule
resource "google_compute_global_forwarding_rule" "default" {
  name                  = "l7-xlb-forwarding-rule"
  project               = var.project_id
  provider              = google-beta
  ip_protocol           = "TCP"
  load_balancing_scheme = "EXTERNAL"
  port_range            = "80"
  target                = google_compute_target_http_proxy.default.id
  ip_address            = google_compute_global_address.l7-xlb-static-ip.address
}

# http proxy
resource "google_compute_target_http_proxy" "default" {
  name     = "l7-xlb-target-http-proxy"
  project               = var.project_id
  provider = google-beta
  url_map  = google_compute_url_map.default.id
}

# url map
resource "google_compute_url_map" "default" {
  name            = "l7-xlb-url-map"
  project               = var.project_id
  provider        = google-beta
  default_service = google_compute_backend_service.fancy-fe-frontend.id
}

# reserved IP address
resource "google_compute_global_address" "l7-xlb-static-ip" {
  provider = google-beta
  project               = var.project_id
  name     = "l7-xlb-static-ip"
  address  = "10.0.0.10"
}
```

And this the error which I see typing: `terraform apply --auto-approve`

```
    module.load_balancer.google_compute_global_address.l7-xlb-static-ip: Creating... ╷ │ 
Error: Error creating GlobalAddress: googleapi: 
Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.address': '10.0.0.10'. Specified IP address is not allocated to the project or does not belong to the specified scope., 
invalid │ │   with module.load_balancer.google_compute_global_address.l7-xlb-static-ip, 
│ on modules\lb\lb.tf line 108, in resource "google_compute_global_address" "l7-xlb-static-ip":
│  108: resource "google_compute_global_address" "l7-xlb-static-ip" {
```

Would someone support me with that and point my failure in th eabove snippet of Terraform code?

Comment: The IPv4 address `10.0.0.10` is not a valid global IP address. That address is an RFC1918 private IP address.